# Поиск через SQL-запрос папки с определённым названием

Tags: sql, plsql, plsql-developer

Скажите пожалуйста, а можно ли через `sql`-запрос найти папку или каталог с заданным названием? К примеру я создаю запрос и мне надо в запросе указать папку с названием допустим `2022`.
Располагает ли такими механизмами `Oracle PL\SQL Developer`?
Без пользовательских и клиентских процедур, чем механически через `SELECT, FROM, WHERE` и так далее.

Comment: Уточните, как именно вы собрались через БД искать какие-то папки и где?

Comment: Типичная XY-problem. *через sql-запрос найти папку или каталог с заданным названием* Ну, допустим, нашёл (или не нашёл) - и что? Формулируйте задачу, а не свои придуманные подходы к её решению.

Comment: выбирайте способы: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/list-files-in-a-directory-from-plsql-and-sql-comparison-of-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL запрос вернет только данные из SQL базы.
Если пути (папки) записаны где-то в таблице, то вы сможете получить их.
Вне базы SQL сам SQL-запрос не работает.